# implement the wireless m-bus protocol on an STM32/CC1120

Tags: stm32

I'm trying to implement the wireless m-bus protocol on an STM32/CC1120 system, but I can't find any useful documentation about the wmbus working principles or any implementation examples.
Can anybody, please, help me find some tutorials/docs/specs ?
Thanks :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something other than programming.

Answer (score 2):

The wireless M-Bus protocol is a part of the european norm EN 13757.

There is a whole series of documents describing the different aspects of M-Bus. Part 4 is for wireless M-Bus.

You can buy the documents at beuth. You'll certainly need part 4 for wireless m-bus and part 3 for detailed decoding of the contained m-bus records:
[EN 13757-4 (W-Mbus)](http://www.beuth.de/en/standard/din-en-13757-4/198860297)
[EN 13757-3 (Application Layer)](http://www.beuth.de/en/standard/din-en-13757-3/165937084)

If you don't want to directly invest money, but learn about the basics, you may also want to have a look at the [OMS (open metering system) specification](https://oms-group.org/fileadmin/files/download4all/omsSpezifikationen/generation4/spezifikation/vol2/OMS-Spec_Vol2_Primary_v442.pdf) which is for free and  based on the wireless-m-bus protocol. Keep in mind that not every wireless m-bus meter is necessarily a OMS meter but it could still help getting you started into the subject.

Comment: @user1810087: Thanks, I updated the link to the concerning volume - it should work again!

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meter-Bus

I also found the description of M-Bus proto in docs for ODIN OD4110 energy meter. But the sources are hard to find. I also need one just to communicate and log the consumption.

Answer (score 1):

There are several libraries available:

- [jMBus](http://mbus4j.sourceforge.net/): supports wireless and is based in Java
- [Mbus4J](https://www.openmuc.org/m-bus/): based on Java
- [libmbus](http://www.rscada.se/libmbus/): don't support wireless, only wires, based on C

Using one of these helps coming around knowing the full M-Bus communication protocol or buying the documents.