# Reading water meters with m-bus protocol

Tags: android, protocols

My goal is to allow users to read water meter data (id's of meters are provided) with an android application. To do that i need a 3rd party device to collect data from water meters via `m-bus protocol` and then my app will receive via Bluetooth or something so i can present them.

I have found a lot of devices, for example, B meters RFM-RBT, that can do exactly what i need but is seems there is no documentations or a library for them.

Is there any open library to scan devices via `m-bus protocol`? Any suggestions how to read the meters are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I actually don't exacatly know what you want to do but I think you mean how to process the incoming data or rather how to answer on this data. So, you may have a look on this lib in java: https://github.com/mjung85/iotsys/tree/master/iotsys-wmbus

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple aspects in your question:

**Documentation for M-Bus and Wireless M-Bus**

Start with [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meter-Bus).

From your link, I assume you are looking for a **wireless** m-bus implementation (not m-bus). Wireless M-Bus is based on M-Bus and is a european norm which you can buy at the usual places. ([See answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22538422/2455604))

A good point to get you started without investing money would be the [OMS Specification](http://oms-group.org/fileadmin/pdf/OMS-Spec_Vol2_Primary_v301.pdf) which is for free and based on the wireless m-bus protocol.

**Documentation for Receivers**

Most receivers will automatically receive the telegrams and give them to you either by request or automatically as soon as you open a bluetooth connection. Typically they transmit the original wireless m-bus telegramm plus some additional receiver information (time of reception, radio signal strength, crcs etc). Contact the corresponding vendors for a description how those are encoded.

**M-Bus Library**

I know of a opensource [mbus library](http://www.rscada.se/libmbus/) but I'm not sure if it can also treat wireless m-bus telegrams, which are slightly different and if you can get that to run on android. Maybe the java-based [jMBus lib](https://www.openmuc.org/m-bus/) linked by wikipedia can work under android. It also supports wireless-mbus according to the text on their site.